# Characterization of Minimal Polynomials with same Residue Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

A *very brief* look on the internet didn't turn up any results, so I hope this is not a duplicate. If it is, feel free to tell me :)

Let $K$ be a field and consider the set $\mathcal{I} \subseteq K[X]$ of monic irreducible polynomials over $K$. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{I}$ given by
$$f \sim g \iff \exists K[X]/(f) \underset{K\text{-Alg}}{\cong} K[X]/(g)$$

> Is there a more *intrinsic* description of $\sim$ in the sense that just by looking at the minimal polynomials we can deduce whether their residue fields agree or not?

Here are some thoughts.

- It is clearly necessary that for $f \sim g$ we need $\deg f = \deg g$ to hold.
- Obviously $(f) = (g) \subseteq K[X]$ implies $f \sim g$, but the converse is false:
   While it holds that $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X) = \mathbb{F}_2 \cong \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X+1)$, we still find $X+1 \notin (X)$.
- If an isomorphism of residue fields comes from an isomorphism of polynomial rings, $f$ and $g$ are related via a change of variables of the form $X \mapsto aX+b$ followed by normalization. This is always the case if $\deg f = \deg g = 1$, but I don't think this is true for higher degrees:
  Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. The minimal polynomial of the former is $X^2-2$, while that of the latter is $X^2 - \frac{1}{2}$. Now $(aX+c)^2-2 = a^2X^2 + 2Xb + b-2 = X^2-\frac{1}{2}$ cannot be solved.
- If the residue fields agree and are given abstractly by some field $L$, the choices of isomorphisms $K[X]/(f) \cong L$ and $K[X]/(g) \cong L$ are determined by elements $\alpha \in L$ and $\beta \in L$ respectively. In other words we have $K(\alpha) = L = K(\beta)$.
  We can write $\beta = a_0 + a_1\alpha + ... + a_d\alpha^d$, which gives us a homomorphism $\beta:K[X] \rightarrow K[X], X \mapsto a_0+a_1X+..+a_dX^d$, which postcomposed with the projection $K[X] \rightarrow K[X]/(f) \cong L$ descends to the prescribed isomorphisms $K[X]/(g) \cong L$. Up until now I am unsure, whether we can retrieve those coefficients $a_0,...,a_d$ from the polynomials $f$ and $g$. I hoped that (if one could do this) $f \sim g$ holds iff the matrix $A$ given by the coefficients of the $\beta(X^k)$ (which should amount to the base-change matrix from the $K$-basis $\{1,\alpha,...,\alpha^d\}$ to $\{1,\beta,...,\beta^d\}$) is invertible. But unfortunately I couldn't make this precise yet..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $K$ is finite, $K=\mathbb{F}_q$ then any two monic irreducibles of degree $k$ give $\mathbb{K}_{q^k}$.

Comment: Yes, this is one reason, why I became interested in this question. I know that the uniqueness of finite fields follows from Galois theory. But maybe there is some adhoc criterion from which we can deduce that all irreducible polynomials in $F_p[X]$ satisfy $f \sim g$...

Comment: For $g$ irreducible then $f\sim g$ iff $\deg f=\deg g$ and $g$ has a root in $K[X]/(f)$, what do you expect more in general?

Comment: Tbh I don't know what to expect. I hoped for some elementary criterion, maybe in terms of plain linear algebra and polynomial divsion involving $f$ and $g$. Atm I am rather tired, so I don't see why your criterion should be easy to test (I suspect it is not). In general I wouldn't be surprised if there is no elementary solution. But this shouldn't refrain me from asking about it...

Comment: When $K=\Bbb{Q}$ you can search for the factorization algorithms in number fields to see why there is no elementary linear algebra criterion. The most naive algorithm sets $F(X)=a f(bX),G(x)=cg(dX),G_2(X)=Disc(f)^{\deg(f)}G(X/Disc(f))$ such that they are in $\Bbb{Z}[X]_{monic}$ and $g$ has a root in $\Bbb{Q}[X]/(f)$ iff $G_2$ has a root in $\Bbb{Z}[X]/(F)$. Factoring $F$ approximately in $\Bbb{C}$ you can compute a bound $N$ such that any root $\sum_{m=0}^{\deg(f)-1} r_m X^m\in \Bbb{Z}[X]/(F)$ of $G_2$ will have $|r_m|< N$, so you can enumerate them all and check if they are a root of $G_2$.